# How to hide image/video if it cannot be loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to hide img/video if it cannot be loaded in website

Comment: Please add minimal code that you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use javascript,for video.

```
x = document.getElementById("video");
x.addEventListener('error',function(){
   $(x).hide();
});
```